# Examples on Using Microsoft Identity Without OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin

I have been searching around the webs to see if it is possible to not use OWIN with MS Identity. Came accross this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics

"OWIN is not required for all of identity 2.0, but specifically we use OWIN as a poor mans DI (CreatePerContext), and also we use owin to generate cookies/do authentication as part of the app. You can use UserManager/RoleManager stand alone without owin (i.e. if you wanted to still use FormsAuth with identity you could)"

Ok, great. I still cannot find any examples on how to do this.

Can anyone shed any insight into using Identity without the OWIN middleware?

Comment: I'm lookinfg for this too. Hope someone can answer this

Answer (score 0):

OWIN is required for setting and reading the cookie. So no, can't throw away OWIN.

You can use OWIN to do authentication without ASP.Net Identity (that's what my current project does), but can't do the other way. What's wrong with OWIN anyway?

Theoretically you can roll your own methods for setting authentication cookie, but what is the point when OWIN does this for you?

Comment: The quote from codeplex above is incorrect then? I'm looking to not use OWIN if I don't need it. No sense in using extraneous frameworks if they aren't needed.

Comment: No, that quote is correct, you can bolt-on old membership provider cookie setting functionality, but that will be a pretty ghetto solution that I can't recommend.

Comment: And yes, I agree, there is a big pile of dependencies chained from Identity, but nothing bad happens if you have them - these are well-thought libraries.

Comment: What if I'm doing an external facing API for partners with authentication per request. I want all the structure (user, roles, etc) but there's no need for authentication cookie. Seems like a lot of extra overhead for something you don't need.

Comment: @RolandSchaer well, in that case you can remove all the authentication cookie. And you can also remove nugets that look like OWIN, but I don't know which are safe to remove, as I have not tried that.